# WebAccount SignOutAsync() is not removing the account/token from the local cache

Tags: uwp, windows-10, single-sign-on, azure-authentication

Our UWP app is using Azure AD for authentication. When I ran the app, I was prompted to log in, which I did and authentication was successful. Now I am unable to return to a "signed out" state. Whenever I run the app, I am signed in automatically. I have called `SignOutAsync()` on the WebAccount, but it appears to have no effect.

First, I call this:

```
private async Task SignOutAccountAsync(WebAccount account)
{
    // remove local settings                
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Remove("CurrentUserWebAccountProviderId");
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Remove("CurrentUserWebAccountId");
    await account.SignOutAsync();                
}
```

And then I call the following, *which succeeds and logs me in without requiring any interaction*.

```
WebTokenRequest wtr = new WebTokenRequest(wap, string.Empty, clientId);
wtrr = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(wtr);
```

How do I sign out and force the user to re-authenticate to the app?

**Edit:** Here's a more cohesive example where I log in, sign out, instantiate all the objects used for login, and then log in again.

```
// silent login
wtrr = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(wtr);
userWebAccount = wtrr.ResponseData.First().WebAccount;

// sign out
await userWebAccount.SignOutAsync();

// use new objects to try again
wap = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync("https://login.microsoft.com", authority);
wtr = new WebTokenRequest(wap, string.Empty, clientId);
wtr.Properties.Add("resource", resource);

// silent login works again, despite having called SignOutAsync().
wtrr = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(wtr);
```

Comment: where do u get "wap" and "clientId" from, are you getting these values from LocalSettings? after removing?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be missing here, that you remove the values from local settings but the objects **wap** and **clientId** still have the values which can be later on user to sign in. So make sure either keep these variables local to a method where you sign in, or if they are local to class then empty them out when signing out.

```
private async Task SignOutAccountAsync(WebAccount account)
{
    // remove local settings                


 ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Remove("CurrentUserWebAccountProviderId");
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Remove("CurrentUserWebAccountId");
    wap = "";
    clientId = "";
    await account.SignOutAsync();                
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ensured that the objects are reinstantiated and the problem persists. I have updated my question with further detail. For the record, the *clientId* and *authority* are static strings that should not change.

Comment: maybe your usecase is different, but from what I see static strings which are alive throughout the app running time, should be enough to hold your cliendiD and other authentication strings, you do not need to store them into settings, unless you need to save the data even when the app is closed.

Comment: I have seen ur updated question but I still do not see why you need to save those values in settings, and where in code are you adding those values in the first place? and after removing I do not see where you are trying to re use those values to login. when u remove the string items from localsettings, try to get them in a variable in the very next line and print them out or debug with break point to make sure whether they got removed or not.